# SQL - how can I add a number like a count to an SQL query so that for each name it displays 1, 2, 3 instead of a total count

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

I’m trying to display all instances of a certain Name. I want to also display the count of each name, incrementing by 1 and then starting back at 1 for the next name.

For example:

```
Michelle 1
Michelle 2
Michelle 3
Fred 1
Fred 2
Steve 1
```

I was told partition but might work but not sure how I can do this count.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select name,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
from t;
```

If you have an ordering in mind, then use the appropriate column for the `order by`.